# mysql left adjust type feature

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a feature in mysql or a function in php that will allow me to auto adjust everything to the column to the left?   Basically I am allowing the user to delete information out of there table but the way the information is set up is in such a way that there can only be null space at n+1 places in my row.  So I need to be able to let the user delete something probably located in the middle of the row and then I will need to adjust all the information located to the right of that empty field one column left.  Thereby eliminating an empty column in my row.  I think that I will just have to perform this operation by manipulating the information in my database to find the null space and then pull all the information out after that place then reinsert it starting at the null space.  But if there is an simpler solution I would love to here about it.Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a real bad database design....

Comment: Could you post a table structure, and describe what your data is? What you're suggesting sounds like you've got a one to many relationship stored in the same table.

Comment: the info is classes that a user says they have taken so the table is set up username,class1,class2 so on and so forth and when the user deletes the entry from column class2 I want to take what is in class3 and class4...... and move that information one column left so that class2 column will no longer be empty and now class4 column will be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing some php code that checked where the row had a null space and then pull all the data out of the row and reinsert the data into the row.  I really dont like that idea but since I dont have anything better I just did that.  And it works that is what is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table
set your_column = ltrim(your_column)
```

[MySQL LTRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim)

Comment: can I do that with php like ("update table set trim(row) where USERNAME='$username'") also I dont care so much about the column  as I do left adjusting the row

Comment: Yes you can put that query in PHP and execute it.

Comment: Or if you don't want to change the record you can adjust the data while selecting it: `select ltrim(your_col) from your_table where username = 'aName'`

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT ltrim('$concant') FROM CLASSES_TAKEN WHERE USERNAME='$username'");  $concant is the column name in a php variable this is not left adjust the information in the database I suppose I could be using it wrong

Comment: I just read that link you left me a little bit more than the first time i looked at it it says that it takes empty space off a string not exactly what I am looking for but thanks anyhow